# how can print only unique Permutations of a string?

Tags: c++, string, permutation

this function prints the Permutations of a string, how can I modify it to make it print only unique Permutations? "no duplicates"

```
void RecPermute(string soFar, string rest) {
  if (rest == "")           // No more characters
    cout << soFar << endl;  // Print the word
  else                      // Still more chars
    // For each remaining char
    for (int i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++) {
      string next = soFar + rest[i];  // Glue next char
      string remaining = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1);
      RecPermute(next, remaining);
    }
}
// "wrapper" function
void ListPermutations(string s) {
  RecPermute("", s);
```

Comment: Save the permutations to a `std::unordered_set`, then print the set.

Comment: the code was repeated twice by mistake. the code ends with the wrapper function

Answer (score 4):

You could use the standard function [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) which creates unique permutations.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void ListPermutations(std::string str) {
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end()); // sort to start at the first permutation

    do {
        std::cout << str << '\n';

        // get the next unique permutation:
    } while( std::next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()) );
}

int main() {
    ListPermutations("aaba");
}
```

Output:

```
aaab
aaba
abaa
baaa
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to use any library function like `std::next_permutation`, you can use backtracking and recursion to solve this problem. The algorithm is the same as permutation with unique characters, but you need to check if the number has been encountered before. If character has been encountered previously, ignore it to avoid duplicates.

Here's the code with comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

void printPermutations(std::string &str, int index) {
    if (index == str.size()) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::set<char> soFar;
    // loop from position index onward
    for (auto i = index; i < str.size(); i++) {
        // check we haven't seen character in loop previously
        if (soFar.find(str[i]) == soFar.end()) {
            // store character in set
            soFar.insert(str[i]);
            // swap index with next character in loop
            std::swap(str[index], str[i]);
            printPermutations(str, index + 1);
            // swap back
            std::swap(str[index], str[i]);
        }
    }
}

// "wrapper" function
void ListPermutations(std::string s) {
    printPermutations(s, 0);
}

int main()
{
    ListPermutations("aaba");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
aaba
aaab
abaa
baaa
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eKETW6d4o)